# recursively collect string blocks in python

Tags: python

I have a custom data file formatted like this:

```
{
    data = {
        friends = {
            max = 0 0,
            min = 0 0,
        },
        family = {
            cars = {
                van = "honda",
                car = "ford",
                bike = "trek",
            },
            presets = {
                location = "italy",
                size = 10,
                travelers = False,
            },
            version = 1,
        },
    },
}
```

I want to collect the blocks of data, meaning string between each set of {} while maintaining a hierarhcy. This data is not a typical json format so that is not a possible solution.

My idea was to create a class object like so

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, header, children):
        self.header = header
        self.children = children
```

Where i would then loop through the data line by line 'somehow' collecting the necessary data so my resulting output would like something like this...

```
Block("data = {}", [
    Block("friends = {max = 0 0,\n min = 0 0,}", []),
    Block("family = {version = 1}", [...])
])
```

In short I'm looking for help on ways I can serialize this into useful data I can then easily manipulate. So my approach is to break into objects by using the {} as dividers.
If anyone has suggestions on ways to better approach this I'm all up for ideas. Thank you again.

So far I've just implemented the basic snippets of code

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self, content, children):
        self.content = content
        self.children = children

def GetBlock(strArr=[]):
    print len(strArr)
#   blocks = []
    blockStart = "{"
    blockEnd = "}"

with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    blocks = GetBlock(strArr=data)
```

Comment: How far have you come so far? Implementing this recursively should be quite easy.

Comment: @filmor I've updated post to show my code so far... I'm a bit stuck though not clear on how to proceed with it.

Comment: what is this mean? 0 0, array? if that one is not exists, you can replace = to : and ast.literal_eval would do that, unless you have = inside strings.

Comment: @YOU 0 0, is data produced by the program outputting this data. It's a custom format which I don't have the ability to change. that data in particular relates to position X Y i believe.

Comment: strings array would be like `van = "honda" "nissan" "toyota"`  too?

Comment: in this case there are no string arrays in this output. the 0 0 is the only ones which appear just like in the exmaple above.

Comment: It might be easiest to use some regex or similar to make this proper JSON, then parse it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `to_block` function that takes the lines from your file as an iterator and recursively creates a nested dictionary from those. (Of course you could also use a custom `Block` class, but I don't really see the benefit in doing so.)

```
def to_block(lines):
    block = {}
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip().endswith(("}", "},")):
            break
        key, value = map(str.strip, line.split(" = "))
        if value.endswith("{"):
            value = to_block(lines)
        block[key] = value
    return block
```

When calling it, you have to strip the first line, though. Also, evaluating the "leafs" to e.g. numbers or strings is left as an excercise to the reader.

```
>>> to_block(iter(data.splitlines()[1:]))
{'data': {'family': {'version': '1,', 
                     'cars': {'bike': '"trek",', 'car': '"ford",', 'van': '"honda",'}, 
                     'presets': {'travelers': 'False,', 'size': '10,', 'location': '"italy",'}}, 
          'friends': {'max': '0 0,', 'min': '0 0,'}}}
```

Or when reading from a file:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    next(f)  # skip first line
    res = to_block(f)
```

---

Alternatively, you can do some preprocessing to transform that string into a JSON(-ish) string and then use `json.loads`. However, I would not go all the way here but instead just wrap the values into `""` (and replace the original `"` with `'` before that), otherwise there is too much risk to accidentally turning a string with spaces into a list or similar. You can sort those out once you've created the JSON data.

```
>>> data = data.replace('"', "'")
>>> data = re.sub(r'= (.+),$',     r'= "\1",', data, flags=re.M)
>>> data = re.sub(r'^\s*(\w+) = ', r'"\1": ',  data, flags=re.M)
>>> data = re.sub(r',$\s*}',       r'}',       data, flags=re.M)
>>> json.loads(data)
{'data': {'family': {'version': '1', 
                     'presets': {'size': '10', 'travelers': 'False', 'location': "'italy'"}, 
                     'cars': {'bike': "'trek'", 'van': "'honda'", 'car': "'ford'"}}, 
          'friends': {'max': '0 0', 'min': '0 0'}}}
```

Comment: this is a great and clever solution that appears to be working for what i need. It's nice that it more or less converts it to json formatting then as well. Much easier to manage now.

Comment: what is your code calling this function look like? `with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
 data = file.read()
 results = to_block(iter(data.splitlines()[1:-1]))`

Comment: @JokerMartini Yes, something like that. It's not optimal that you have to read the file in full first, though. Guess you could wrap that in another function that will handle the first and last lines appropriately.

Comment: @JokerMartini I updated the code so you only have to skip the first line. Now it should work better with reading files line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do with ast or json with the help of regex substitutions.

```
import re

a = """{
    data = {
        friends = {
            max = 0 0,
            min = 0 0,
        },
        family = {
            cars = {
                van = "honda",
                car = "ford",
                bike = "trek",
            },
            presets = {
                location = "italy",
                size = 10,
                travelers = False,
            },
            version = 1,
        },
    },
}"""

#with ast
a = re.sub("(\w+)\s*=\s*", '"\\1":', a)
a = re.sub(":\s*((?:\d+)(?: \d+)+)", lambda x:':[' + x.group(1).replace(" ", ",") + "]", a)
import ast
print ast.literal_eval(a)
#{'data': {'friends': {'max': [0, 0], 'min': [0, 0]}, 'family': {'cars': {'car': 'ford', 'bike': 'trek', 'van': 'honda'}, 'presets': {'travelers': False, 'location': 'italy', 'size': 10}, 'version': 1}}}

#with json
import json
a = re.sub(",(\s*\})", "\\1", a)
a = a.replace(":True", ":true").replace(":False", ":false").replace(":None", ":null")
print json.loads(a)
#{u'data': {u'friends': {u'max': [0, 0], u'min': [0, 0]}, u'family': {u'cars': {u'car': u'ford', u'bike': u'trek', u'van': u'honda'}, u'presets': {u'travelers': False, u'location': u'italy', u'size': 10}, u'version': 1}}}
```

Comment: Nice, but this would not work if there are e.g. string lists like `van = "honda" "crysler",` and might stumble upon some other non-conformities not shown in the example.

Comment: @tobias_k, I didn't add that, since OP does not seems to need it and normally regex solutions are one time approach for quick and dirty.